# How to serve all devices under the same network using 'create-react-app' and 'http-server'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I can't access the app built with `create-react-app` from other devices on the same network using http-server package.

If i use `http-server` to serve an other react project it works fine to access the app from any device on the same network. But using `create-react-app` i can access the app only through the device which hosts the app, whether i use `http-server` or `pushstate-server` as suggested after running `npm run build`.

Any idea to solve this?

**EDIT**

I first create the build folder running `npm run build` and then I serve the build folder with `http-server` running `http-server -p 9999 -o` from the build folder and it works from my laptop which hosts the app, database and the API REST server, but if i try to access the app from another device on the same network using the laptop's ip address (connecting to e.g. 192.168.1.14:9999 from the smartphone's browser) it doesn't load anything returning `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error from the browser .

Doing the same exact steps for another project that doesn't use create-react-app works fine for all devices connected to the same wifi network accessing the laptop's ip address (e.g connecting to e.g. 192.168.1.14:9999 from the smartphone's browser).

Comment: Coud you explain how you are using http-server with that project? `create-react-app` merely generates a project that includes a command to run a webpack dev server. But that in itself is not for production. You simply build the bundle.js file and then need to serve that somehow using a webserver.

Comment: *i try to access the app from another device on the same network using the laptop's ip address*: this is the relevant part. How are you doing that? Do you have firewall blocking your `9999` port to other devices? ...

Comment: @nbkhope I edited the post to answer your question.

Comment: @RaphaMex I connect to e.g. 192.168.1.14:9999 (laptop's ip address on the port 9999) from a smartphone's browser . My firewall is not blocking my 9999 port because if i do the same steps to build and serve another project that doesn't use create-react-app it works perfectly from  all devices on the same network connecting to 192.168.1.14:9999

Comment: Try `-a 192.168.1.14`. Looks useless but maybe http-server restricts to `localhost` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run start`.
 
Afterwards open the url from another device on the network.

In your case, `192.168.1.14:9999` would work.

[Documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/docusaurus/docs/advanced-configuration.md) for setting HOST environment variables.